# store an array of files in an already existing session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

i have a session array called $_SESSION['CART'] i already use it to store details of cart items
now i want to store multiple uploaded files names of files that user uploads while adding this item to cart as part of the session cart.i want to store them with key files. this is what am doing but its not working. is there a way for me to achieve this

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = 
    array(
            'id'=>$productid, 
            'quantity'=>$quantity, 
            'detail'=>$detail, 
            'files'=>$files
    );
```

Comment: `but its not working`-> what is not working?

Comment: storing an array of file names along with my existing array@AlivetoDie

Comment: what was the error or problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing much to explain here. if you want to store multiple array inside of array to store multiple file names. I assume that $files is a single file name only.
Try this.

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
    array(
        'id'=>$productid, 
        'quantity'=>$quantity, 
        'detail'=>$detail, 
        'files'=>$files
    )
);
```

Comment: files is multiple files. and i want to attach this multiple files to a cart item, the next cart item will have its own multiple files

Comment: when you said files do you mean you want to store the file name only? Am I right?

Comment: Is this `$files` an array or a string?

Comment: yes i want to store multiple file names only. its an array not string

Comment: My answer is right instead of using `$_SESSION['cart'][]` use `$_SESSION['cart']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $_SESSION array like this way, try to use buffer variable to prepare data for session:

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cart[] = array(
        'id'       => $productid, 
        'quantity' => $quantity, 
        'detail'   => $detail, 
        'files'    => $files
);
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
```